# Huggingface, The illogical question why "WordLevelTrainer can only train a WordLevel"?

Tags: python, huggingface-tokenizers, huggingface

As part of an NLP course I was provided this code:

```
MIN_FREQ = 3 # words appearing fewer than 3 times are treated as 'unknown'
unk_token = '[UNK]'
pad_token = '[PAD]'

tokenizer = Tokenizer(WordLevel(unk_token=unk_token))
tokenizer.pre_tokenizer = Whitespace()
tokenizer.normalizer = normalizers.Lowercase()

trainer = WordLevelTrainer(min_frequency=MIN_FREQ, special_tokens=[pad_token, unk_token])
tokenizer.train_from_iterator(train_data['text'], trainer=trainer)
```

And I wondered "why is the trainer split from the model? why would you want to be able to train a model with the wrong trainer?" so I did the only reasonable thing one has to do and changed the models and trainers.

Short story shorter, they only train their own respective models and error out otherwise.
eg: "WordLevelTrainer can only train a WordLevel"

Thus I ask again, why are they, interface-wise two different objects and are initialized in different parts of the code? what benefit is there other than my own perplexity about software engineering?

Comment: No doubt the `WordLevel` and `WordLevelTrainer` were written by the same engineer(s), and they made assumptions about the implementation.  You wouldn't pass a word-based model to a numeric-based trainer.

Comment: @TimRoberts this however doesn't reason why you need 2 classes for that, what's the benefit in abstraction?

Comment: That principle is called "design not to preclude".  The abstraction ALLOWS for a trainer to work with multiple models, even if this particular implementation doesn't do that.  It is surprisingly difficult to design a flexible interface that both functions reasonably and survives future requirements.

Comment: That's all well, why would anyone reasonably want this kind of pattern in this case? Are there implementations that use this feature in huggingface?

Comment: The objects have different (although related) behaviors.  There's really no advantage to combining them, and having them be separate enables future designs we can't anticipate today.